# Change CSV filetype without opening

Tags: python, excel, windows, csv, pandas

Is it possible to use Python or R to change a CSV (comma delimited) file to become a Windows CSV file without actually reading it into memory using some Pandas style API?[image]

I have a need to convert regular Comma Delimited CSV files to Windows CSV files, but reading them in using the Pandas API or opening them in Excel to re-save in new format would be costly (and probably impossible once they get too large, they are shipped in huge chunks).

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you need to change between the formats, for context?

Comment: @asongtoruin Sure, context is that I am reading in the CSVs using the Pandas API within python, and there is a Parsing error that happens on the regular CSV formatted files that does not happen with the Windows Comma Separated files. The files are too numerous and are shipped too large to open in Excel and resave each one.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could show a small example of what your CSV files look like: post a few lines from one of your original CSV files and a few lines from a 'Windows' CSV file.

Comment: @Xukrao they look the same when opened. In my question I note whether this is possible without opening them at all because they are too large. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could write a loop where in each iteration you read out a single line from the original CSV file, convert it, and then write it to a new CSV file. With this approach there's never more than one single text line in memory at any time, so it should work for arbitrarily large files.

Comment: "I am reading in the CSVs using the Pandas API within python, and there is a Parsing error that happens on the regular CSV formatted files that does not happen with the Windows Comma Separated files." The Pandas CSV reader function has a great amount of configurable settings. If you post your parsing error, then maybe people here could also help you find a Pandas setting that will solve the parsing error directly.